# git commit directory

Tags: git, github

I created a repo and, locally, dragged-and-dropped an existing project directory into the repo. I then did something like git add directory/ and committed it and pushed it. When I look at my repo on github though, all i see is the directory with no subfolders, no content. How do I push all of the files and subfolders of that project to the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are in your local commit, then they should be displayed on Github.

Load up gitk (just type gitk from your Git bash command prompt); and check to see whether all the files below the folder were actually added in the commit you pushed to Github.

If they weren't, and a git add . doesn't seem to be working, check that your .gitignore isn't excluding them for some reason.

Comment: thanks for the response. I loaded up gitk and (on the right hand panel) saw the folders i was expecting when i clicked to view tree. Does this mean the files were added to the commit? 

Also, can you explain how to check gitignore? and maybe what gitignore is, conceptually, altogether? ;)

Comment: .gitignore is a file you have to create by hand which contains rules for excluding certain files you don't want pushed into your repo when you add a directory. For instance if you had some .config files that contained sensitive information like connection strings you could write a rule in .gitignore to ignore those whenever you make commits. You have to add these by hand though, so this probably isn't the source of your problem.

Comment: Also, try git status in your root directory of your repo. This should show you what's actually in your local repo.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ git add directory/*
```

(or *.h, *.c, and so on).

and then check as Aaronontheweb suggests (with `gitk` or `git status`) that the files are included in the staging area. Not only the folder name.

Comment: tested with msysgit on windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git add .` from the base project folder - this should recursively add all files to the repo.

Comment: This is completely equivalent to `git add <directory>`. `.` is just another way of specifying a path.

Comment: Not good if there are files in the folder that the user does not want to add.

Comment: Then write a .gitignore or use a tool like Git Extensions to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
`$ git add directory1 directory2 director3`
This will add the above directories along with all the files present in respective directory.
You can conform by :
`$ git status`
This should show all the files that will be present in next commit.