# git add . not including all the directory content .

Tags: git, git-commit

I m trying to push a repository to github.com . After following their instructions

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/VihaanVerma89/RandomSolutions.git
git push -u origin master
```

I see that my project bin and src folder are empty on github  , a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425082/git-commit-directory) solved this issue by

```
git add .
```

However after following this advice I still see that some files are not getting staged for commit. gitk shows Local uncommited changes, not checked to index (check the last image).
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your .gitignore say?

Comment: I haven't put anything in .gitignore.

Comment: It seems like `git add .` should work...what happens if you do `git reset HEAD && git add .`?  (Make sure you don't include the `--hard` option when you reset)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to help :\

Comment: And you're not doing anything between `git add .` and `git status` (e.g. building)?

Comment: nope that is why I posted the image. Having the project open in eclipse shouldn't make any problem right ?

Comment: It probably isn't causing your problem.

Comment: gitk shows Local uncommited changes, not checked to index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot of your first commit in github, `bin` and `src` were tracked by git as submodules.

That is to say, when you were adding all the files, there were `.git` directories in `bin` and `src`. So the simplest way to solve your problem is delete all `.git` directories except the root one.

Comment: right on man ! . I guess I even tried adding the src/ and bin/ manually with each files name , may be that created an additional .git directory in the sub folders.